# Could deleting a file from the folder of a program, not just remove something from the program, but also modify the program?

Tags: linux, windows

For example: could I change a characters movement speed in a video game, by removing a file from the games directory, or would such a thing require me to *modify* a file rather than removing one. Sorry for the newbie, and admittedly strange question. I'm asking because I wanna,know if removing  a file from a programs folder, could cause such a thing.

Comment: as discussed, not generally, and certainly not going to work for game modding, but it is possible that a program was specifically written to change its behaviors based on the existance/non-existance of a resource. consider for instance an app that uses a config file, but the config file is per-user (so its stored in the users profile dir). on first run, the file doesn't exist, so the program is written to check for the file, and if it doesn't exist it will create it from defaults. if you later delete the config file again, the program will recreate it. but that was written into the code.

Comment: There are some games, especially older ones, where plain text config files control aspects of the game and modifying them was fun. Modern games don't usually do this. Competitive and online games in particular do not work like this, and manipulating these files on those sorts of games in a sure way to get yourself banned and blocked as a cheater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it would require modification. The character's movement speed is defined somewhere. It needs to be, as game characters have no "natural" walking speed that could be inferred from somewhere. If you would remove that definition, the game would try to lookup the character's speed when you try to move and it would most likely crash with a so-called *segmentation fault*. This error means the program is trying to access data that doesn't exist (or it's not allowed to access). However, in practice the game would most likely crash way before that, because it knows a certain file should exist, tries to load it and the file doesn't exist. Also modern anti-cheat detection would almost certainly kick in when you start modifying game files.

How this is usually achieved (or used to at least, I haven't played games in a long time) is to change the memory of the game when it's running. If you can figure out that the max movement speed is stored in memory at address X, you can go in and change that value. That's how [trainers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trainer_(games)) work(ed). Same for in-game currency, wall collision, health, ammo, whatever the game stores in memory. But again, modern anti-cheat would most likely detect this.

Of course this could work different for mods. Mods override the built-in behavior of a game. If you'd remove the mod, the game would have it's own internal definitions to fall back on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. Very helpful!